# URL Changes but the view fails to change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

When I view the page in Google Chrome and I click on the goal list that has been generated the URL changes to `URL/#/tabs/personalview` but the view fails to change.

This is the code in my `personalGoals.html` file:

```
<ion-view view-title="PersonalGoals">
  <ion-content class="has-footer">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="goal in goals" href="#/tabs/personalview">
      <span class="goal-lists">{{goal.goaltitle}}</span>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is the code in my `app.js` file:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');

  $stateProvider

.state('tabs', {
        url: '/tabs',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })

.state('tabs.personal', {
        url: '/personal',
        views: {
          'personalGoals-view': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/personalGoals.html',
            controller: 'personalCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

.state('tabs.personalview', {
        url: '/personalview',
        templateURL: 'templates/test.html',
        controller: 'personalViewCtrl'
      })

.state('tabs.relationship', {
        url: '/relationship',
        views: {
          'relationshipGoals-view': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/relationshipGoals.html',
            controller: 'relationshipCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

.state('tabs.squad', {
        url: '/squad',
        views: {
          'squadGoals-view': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/squadGoals.html',
            controller: 'squadCtrl'
          }
        }
      });
      // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('tabs/dashboard');
    });
```

You can see the full code over [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gWCyERKVRCP36MpNmdVu?p=info).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Try use `ui-sref` instead of `href`.

Comment: Can you provide a fully functional plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're trying to navigate to the wrong URL.

You are trying to navigate to the state name when you should be navigating to the state URL.

There are two ways to do this:

1. You can continue to use href, and change the URL to #/personalview
2. You can use ui-sref instead of href and do something like ui-sref="tabs.personalview"

You might check out the following for reference:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/using-ui-router-navigate-ionicframework/

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/12/using-nested-states-angularjs-ui-router/

Best,

Comment: however it worked with only `.state('test', {});` using `href="#/test"` without the tabs as a parent... but resulted with only a blank page and the test.html contents which is `<ion-nav-view name="test-view">Hello</ion-nav-view>`

Comment: I made this last year.  It uses tabs similarly to how you are.  I haven't tested it recently, but it should still work.  I'm wondering now if you have errors in things that you're not presenting on stack overflow.  https://github.com/nraboy/ionic-imgur-app

Comment: There are no errors from the console... it's just that (in the updated code) it's redirecting to /dashboard...